# Switch database using routes

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Here's my scenario:

I Have a single app, but I need to switch the database connection by route.

Example:

```
switch(route)
{
    case(URL/A):
    { 
        USE DATABASE 1 
    }
    case(URL/B):
    { 
        USE DATABASE 2
    }
    DEFAULT:
        USE DATABASE DEFAULT
 }
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Three opening `{` but only two closing `}` in your code snippet.

Comment: Simple answer, yes but there are plenty of gotchas associated with this. Are the two entities identical? Is it only the connection that differs?

Comment: Yeah Peter, all entities is the same, only data is diferent

Comment: Uwe Keim, this is normal in a switch case.

Comment: Peter, how can i do this?

Comment: How are you creating your context right now? Are you using DI? `new`ing up manually?

Comment: David, i'm using DI

Comment: It may need some form of inheritance but this is not something I've ever attempted.

Comment: Use Repository Pattern and DI

Comment: Register your context and use factory method for dynamically creating context with specified connection string based on current route. If the databases are same and just data is different this should work easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using ASP.NET MVC, your routes depends on your controllers. Then you can imagine having ControllerA using DatabaseA and ControllerB using DatabaseB.

To use multiple database connections, you need a connection string for each one of them.

I would use the following pieces of code to inject instances of DbContextOptionsBuilder inside of Startup.ConfigureServices()

```
var ContextAOptionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ContextA>();
var ContextBOptionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ContextB>();
```

Then you can configure your builders this way (depending on your parameters)

```
ContextAOptionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ContextAConnectionString"), builder =>
        {
            builder.EnableRetryOnFailure(5, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30), null);
        });
ContextAOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
```

Then you can inject them as singletons this way :

```
services.AddSingleton(typeof(DbContextOptionsBuilder<ContextA>),ContextAOptionsBuilder);
```

You can use a BaseController, whose constructor parameters can access to services this way :

```
public BaseController(IConfiguration configuration, IMemoryCache memoryCache,
        IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor,
        DbContextOptionsBuilder<ContextA> ContextAOptionsBuilder,
        DbContextOptionsBuilder<ContextB> ContextBOptionsBuilder){}
```

Of course, ControllerA and ControllerB being heir classes of BaseController, you can access desired builder quite simply.

```
  public ControllerA(IConfiguration configuration,
                     IMemoryCache cache, 
                     IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor, 
                     DbContextOptionsBuilder<ContextA> ContextAOptionsBuilder,
                     DbContextOptionsBuilder<ContextB> ContextBOptionsBuilder)
    :base(configuration, cache, contextAccessor, ContextAOptionsBuilder,ContextBOptionsBuilder)
    { 
         //Create your DbContext using the builder
    }
```

This way you can use one, the other, or both database to build your context

A simpler way would have been injecting your configuration file and building your context from it's content but ppumkin's comment suggested it's a bad idea to do this at a controller level.

This solution is working for me in an ASP.NET Core MVC application, I am still learning the framework but maybe my answer gave you precisions about multiple DbContexts.

Answer (score 0):

You can create 3 connection string also 3 data access Classes. First of your class uses for example DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges others use CreateDatabaseIfNotExists. When you call first class your database creates when you need others there will no need recreate it.

Comment: Inside a repository context. Please dont do this at controller level. Create a repository than can take different configs and easily swappable by DI

Answer (score 0):

Register your context (as scoped, per request) and use factory method for dynamically creating context with specified connection string based on current route (which should be available from `HttpContext` or something similar). If the databases schemas are same and just data is different this should work easily. I can't provide a snippet for you because it's mostly depends on what DI framework you have.